# Change alt-attribute of images with empty alt=""

Tags: jquery, image

I want to detect and change all empty alt tags (alt="") of a site with some text. I tried various things with jQuery, but none of them worked.

e.g.

```
$('img:has(img[alt=""])').attr('alt', 'Alternative text');
```

Where is may mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use just the plain `img[alt=""]` selector string alone:

```js
$('img[alt=""]').prop('alt', 'Alternative text');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img alt="" src="badsrc">
```